# Trying to get rid of self executing parenthesis

Tags: javascript

I got the closure to work, but what I'd like to do is get rid of the parenthesis if I could:

```js
window.obj = {}
obj.method = (function() {
 var closure

 return function(value) {
  if (arguments.length) {
   closure = value
  } else {
   return closure
  }
 }
})();

obj.method(3.14)
$('body').append(obj.method())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Q: Is there any way to get rid of the leading ( and the trailing )()?

Comment: `obj.method = function(value) {
  if (arguments.length) {
   closure = value
  } else {
   return closure
  }
 }`

Comment: Thanks Rayon! But the function has to be executed in order for the closure to take effect.

Comment: -Philip, I just considered `closure` variable as undefined.. In other cases, you need to execute function expression immediately...

Comment: `obj.method(Math.PI)` ;)

Comment: The leading `(` is not necessary, since by virtue of being on the right hand side of an assignment statement, this is already a function expression. As for the parentheses at the end, by definition if you want to create a function with a "private" variable you're going to have to define a surrounding function to define that private variable, and execute the function to set it in motion.

Comment: I **do** want a private variable called closure.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.obj = {}
obj.init = function() {
   var closure
   return result
   function result(value) {
      if (arguments.length) {
         closure = value
      } else {
         return closure
      }
   }
}
obj.method = obj.init()
obj.method(Math.PI)
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = obj.method()
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: You've done nothing more than moved the parentheses from after the function to the call to `obj.init()`.